# cakephp Ajax Form validation doesn't work

Tags: jquery, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp ajax validation for contact us page in my website but it doesnt seem to work at all.Contact us page uses Blockcontents controller with an action contact.IT doesnt give me any errors but doesnt work as planned.Following is my validation.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#name').blur(function(){
      $.post('/blacknovaPHSVN/BlockContents/validate_form',
      { field:$('#name').attr('id'),value:$('#name').val()},
      handleNameValidation
      );
    });
    function handleNameValidation(error){
        if(error.length >0){
            if($('#name-notEmpty').length==0){
               $('#name').after('<div id="name-notEmpty" class="error-message">' + error + "</div>");
            }
        }
        else{
            $('#name-notEmpty').remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Following is the code in my BlockContents controller

```
public function validate_form(){
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
        $this->request->data['Contact'][$this->request['data']['field']] = $this->request['data']['value'];
        $this->Contact->set($this->request->data);
        if($this->Contact->validates()){
            $this->autoRender=False;

        }
 else {
     $error= $this->validateErrors($this->Contact());
    $this->set('error',$this->Contact->validationErrors[$this->request['data']['field']][0]);
    pr($this->request);
    // pr($error[$field]);
 }
    }
}
```

I have also created validate_form.ctp to echo the error.I cant just figure out what seems to be wrong

Comment: What do you mean "doesnt work as planned"? It doesn't save anything or the name doesn't validate or what?

Comment: IT doesn't validate the name field

Comment: And what's the code for your validate_form view?

Comment: <?php echo $error ; ?>

Answer (score 1):

Instead  of: `$error= $this->validateErrors($this->Contact());`

write this: `$error= $this->validateErrors($this->Contact);`

then check output and also change

`if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax())` to `if ($this->request->is('ajax'))`.

It may solve your problem.